# Derivative of $\text{trace}((a|S^{-1}| + bS^{-1})B)$ with respect to $S$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus

I'd like to calculate the derivative of $\text{trace}((a|S^{-1}| + bS^{-1})B)$ with respect to $S$. Here, $a$ and $b$ are scalars, $S$ is a symmetric, non-singular matrix, $B$ is positive semi-definite and $|X|$ denotes the absolute value of $X$ i.e. the matrix which shares the same eigenvectors as $X$ but whose eigenvalues are the absolute value of those of $X$.

The only problem term really is $|S^{-1}| = Q|D^{-1}|Q^T$ for $S = QDQ^T$.

If someone could also point to some useful literature to become more familiar with matrix calculus then that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Useful reference on matrix calculus: 
1. Magnus, Jan R. (1999). Matrix differential calculus with applications in statistics and econometrics. Neudecker, Heinz. (Rev. ed.). New York: John Wiley. ISBN 0-471-98632-1. OCLC 40467399.
2. Are Hjorunges, Complex-Valued Matrix Derivatives: With Applications in Signal Processing and Communications, 2011.

Comment: When you say, absolute value of matrix, I think you mean element-wise operation, correct?

Also, can you give some context (or use case) where you need such a gradient?

Comment: @user550103 element-wise in the sense that it only operates on the eigenvalues of the matrix. Context: it has appeared in some optimisation problem I am trying to solve i.e. I have some objective which is a function of S and this appears as a term.

Answer (score 2):

$
\def\p{\partial}
\def\g#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\R{\operatorname{Reshape}}
\def\S{\operatorname{sign}}
\def\v{\operatorname{vec}}
\def\M{\operatorname{Mat}}
$The absolute value function that you're using can defined using Higham's [Matrix Sign function](https://nhigham.com/2020/12/15/what-is-the-matrix-sign-function/)
$$\eqalign{
G &= \S(S) = S^{-1}\big(S^2\big)^{1/2} \\
A &= |S| = SG = GS = \big(S^2\big)^{1/2} \\
}$$
Note that for these functions, the function of the inverse equals the  inverse of the function
$$\eqalign{
\S(S^{-1}) &= S\big(S^{-2}\big)^{1/2} &= G^{-1} \\
|S^{-1}| &= S^{-1}G^{-1} &= A^{-1} \\
}$$

The differential of $A$ has a simple relationship to that of $S$
$$\eqalign{
A^2 &= S^2 \\
A\,dA + dA\,A &= S\,dS + dS\,S \\
}$$
This expression can be [vectorized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)#Compatibility_with_Kronecker_products) with the aid of the Kronecker product $(\otimes)$ and sum $(\oplus)$
$$\eqalign{
(I\otimes A + A^T\otimes I)\,da &= (I\otimes S+S^T\otimes I)\,ds \\
(I\otimes A + A\otimes I)\,da &= (I\otimes S+S\otimes I)\,ds \\
(A\oplus A)\,da &= (S\oplus S)\,ds \\
da &= (A\oplus A)^{-1}(S\oplus S)\,ds \\
  &= M\,ds \\
}$$
where the combined coefficient matrix $M$ inherits the symmetry of $A$ and $S$.

Your objective function can be rewritten using the Frobenius product $(:)$ and differentiated.
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= B:(\alpha A^{-1} +\beta S^{-1}) \\
d\phi &= B:(\alpha\,dA^{-1} + \beta\,dS^{-1}) \\
 &= -B:(\alpha A^{-1}dA\,A^{-1} + \beta S^{-1}dS\,S^{-1}) \\
 &= -\big(\alpha A^{-1}BA^{-1}:dA + \beta S^{-1}BS^{-1}:dS\big) \\
 &= -\Big(\v(\alpha A^{-1}BA^{-1}):da + \v(\beta S^{-1}BS^{-1}):ds\Big) \\
 &= -\Big(\v(\alpha A^{-1}BA^{-1}):M^Tds + \v(\beta S^{-1}BS^{-1}):ds\Big) \\
 &= -\Big(M\v(\alpha A^{-1}BA^{-1}) + \v(\beta S^{-1}BS^{-1})\Big):ds \\
\g{\phi}{s}
 &= -\Big(M\v(\alpha A^{-1}BA^{-1}) + \v(\beta S^{-1}BS^{-1})\Big) \\
}$$
It is easy to convert this gradient between vector and matrix forms
$$\eqalign{
\g{\phi}{S} &= \R\left(\g{\phi}{s},\;n,\,n\right)
 &= \M\left(\g{\phi}{s}\right) \\
\g{\phi}{s} &= \R\left(\g{\phi}{S},\;n^2,\,{\tt1}\right)
 &= \v\left(\g{\phi}{S}\right) \\
}$$

Comment: Hi @greg. Thanks for your helpful reply. I just have a question... On the 6th equality in the derivation of the gradient:
you go from a $\text{vec}(\alpha A^{-1}BA^{-1}) : M^Tds$ to $M \text{vec}(\alpha A^{-1}BA^{-1}) : ds$. I don't see how this is the case?

Comment: @mrjoeybux Terms in a trace/Frobenius product can be rearranged in a number of different ways, e.g.
$$A:BC \;=\; B^TA:C \;=\; AC^T:B$$
To see this, go back to the cyclic property of the trace and the product definition
$$X:Y = {\rm Tr}(XY^T)$$